# Regex a string with variable whitespace and a newline

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following string I am trying to search for:

```
<td></td>
<td>)</td>
```

There can be any number of spaces between the `</td>` and `<td>` besides the newline. There will always be only one newline but an expression that simply ignores all whitespace (including newlines) is fine.

I'm trying to figure out how to perform a string replacement using this information *without* collapsing all of the whitespace in the file. I found many solutions with an expression that handles whitespace but nothing that I have been able to make work with a newline as well.

My regex experience is limited. How should I approach this problem from a bash shell environment?

Comment: use dom [ and xpath ] to manipulate html documents

Comment: You haven't said exactly what you're trying to replace with what. If you read up on regex in, for example, `sed` or `awk`, you'll find options for recognizing newlines.

Comment: Please show example output (after replacement)

Comment: Then there's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: What do you want to replace in the outfile? Something within the tags or those two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to match an empty `<td>` tag pair followed by a newline and a `<td>` tag pair with a single closing parenthesis in it (with any amount of spaces after the first `</td>` and/or before the second `<td>`). If that's correct try the following expression:

```
<td></td> *\n *<td>)</td>
```

Beware that `sed` normally doesn't support multiline matches, so you need to work with labels and append the next line to the current line before doing the substitution (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/1630171) for a full explanation):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s|<td></td> *\n *<td>)</td>|...|g' infile >outfile
```

Replace the ellipsis (`...`) with your actual replacement text.

Comment: This works perfectly. I had to edit a typo (!$ should be $!); still awaiting peer review.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>\s*?\)?\s*?</td>
```

This will match a  with an optional ) and any number of whitespace between the tags.
I'm unsure though, whether it is the string you're actually looking for?

However, the gist of it is using **\s** as the character class for whitespaces, inclusive newline.

Comment: No need to use reluctant quantifiers IMO.

Comment: Possible, but as far as I can see there's no harm in having them in this expression either.

Comment: It depends on what you're matching but they can be slower. If taking a shorter match is not preferred or even possible, then it's best to stick with greedy quantifiers. In this case `\\s*?\)` the shortest and the longest possible match are always the same and reluctant quantifier only results in lots of backtracking.